# How to increase heap size in Corb2 on MarkLogic

Tags: javascript, unix, marklogic, marklogic-corb

I am trying to run a deletion framework that I created which has a very huge amount of data. While trying to run Corb2, I get the below warning and sometimes an error because of insufficient memory as well.

```
WARNING: Slow receive! Consider increasing max heap size and using -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Error:

```
Sep 23, 2021 1:06:23 PM com.marklogic.developer.corb.QueryUrisLoader closeRequestAndSession
INFO: closing uris session
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:190)
        at com.marklogic.io.IOHelper.literalStringFromReader(IOHelper.java:50)
        at com.marklogic.io.IOHelper.literalStringFromStream(IOHelper.java:66)
        at com.marklogic.http.MultipartBuffer.getBodyAsString(MultipartBuffer.java:75)
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.AbstractResultSequence.instantiateResultItem(AbstractResultSequence.java:138)
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.StreamingResultSequence.next(StreamingResultSequence.java:147)
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.StreamingResultSequence.next(StreamingResultSequence.java:166)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.QueryUrisLoader.populateQueue(QueryUrisLoader.java:212)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.QueryUrisLoader.createAndPopulateQueue(QueryUrisLoader.java:201)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.QueryUrisLoader.open(QueryUrisLoader.java:122)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager.runUrisLoader(Manager.java:809)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager.populateQueue(Manager.java:830)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager.run(Manager.java:578)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager.main(Manager.java:138)
```

Has anybody used it (especially with JavaScript) to be able to work on larger volumes of data?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to find the right size of memory to allocate to hold all of the URIs in-memory, enable the [**DISK-QUEUE**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#DISK-QUEUE) option to allow for the URIs queue to spill to disk in a temporary file that is consumed, instead of all being held in-memory.

You can optionally configure the path for the temp files to be written with [**DISK-QUEUE-TEMP-DIR**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#DISK-QUEUE-TEMP-DIR). If not specified, it will use the **TEMP-DIR**, or `java.io.tmpdir`.